# Matplotib Graph Display Error

Tags: python, matplotlib

Plotted a graph in Matplotlib ,but as you can see from the below image [img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BVZC.png) the points(ticks) are too close to each other.Is there a way to increase distance between the ticks without affecting anything,I have searched a lot but didn't find anything good ,My code is below:

```
 import MySQLdb
 import sys
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 from collections import Counter, OrderedDict

 # open a database connection
 connection = MySQLdb.connect()
 # prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
 cursor = connection.cursor ()

 # execute the SQL query using execute() method.
 cursor.execute ()

 #fetch all of the rows from the query
 data = cursor.fetchall()
 ddt =  sorted(set(data))

 #Shows the Count values
 coll = Counter(data)
 orddict = OrderedDict(sorted(coll.items()))# Sorts the dates in order
 y = orddict.values()
 temp = 0
 a= []
 i = 1
 j = 0
 for x in y:
   temp = temp + x
   if i % 7 == 0:
      a.insert(j,temp)
      temp = 0
      j = j + 1
   i =  i + 1
 b = 0
 dist = [b] + a
 x = range(len(y))
 plt.plot(dist ,color='green', linewidth = 2,marker='o', 
 markerfacecolor='blue', markersize=8)
 plt.ylabel('Number of Bookings')
 plt.xlabel('Date')
 plt.xticks( x,ddt[::7],fontsize = 5, rotation = 90)
 plt.show()

 #close the cursor object
 cursor.close ()

 #close the connection
 connection.close ()

 #exit the program
 sys.exit()
```

Edit 1 :Did as per suggested in the comments ,but now the graph looks like [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFHSK.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to slice the ticks similarly to the ticklabels.

```
plt.xticks( x[::7], ddt[::7], fontsize = 5, rotation = 90)
```

On the other hand it could well be that you want to define `x = range(len(dist))`, such that

```
plt.xticks( x, ddt[::7], fontsize = 5, rotation = 90)
```

shows the desired ticks.

Comment: Did that , it got the xticks right, but unfortunately the values that i plot stay as it is.

Comment: I added another  image in the question ,can you help me with that?

Comment: No, see Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example if further help is needed.

Comment: I went through the link, and have added my whole code, please do check

Comment: Seems like `dist` has indeed roughly 7 times less data points than `y` so I say the output is expected.

Comment: I was confused with the range, got that right now.Thank you.